# MySQL - how to calculate the number of occurrences of an id in the whole table

Tags: mysql

I have a database that contains two tables. A client table and a user table.

**Client Table**

| ClientID | ClientName | UserId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Client A | 1 |
| 1 | Client A | 2 |
| 1 | Client A | 3 |
| 2 | Client B | 1 |
| 2 | Client B | 2 |
| 2 | Client C | 4 |
| 3 | Client C | 1 |
| 3 | Client C | 5 |

**Users Table**

| UserID | userName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | User 1 |
| 2 | User 2 |
| 3 | User 3 |
| 4 | User 4 |
| 5 | User 5 |

And I want to get this result

| ClientID | ClientName | UserName | occurence of user with other client |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Client A | User 1 | 2 |
| 1 | Client A | User 2 | 1 |
| 1 | Client A | User 3 | 0 |

Could you please help me ? Here's what I tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT CT.clientid, 
                CT.clientname, 
                UT.username, 
                Count(UT.userid IN (SELECT ct.userid 
                                      FROM   ct)) 
FROM   clienttable CT 
       LEFT JOIN usertable UT 
              ON UT.userid = CT.userid 
WHERE  CT.clientid = 1
```

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT c.ClientID, 
       c.ClientName, 
       u.userName,
       ( SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM Client c1
         WHERE c.UserID = c1.UserID
           AND c.ClientID != c1.ClientID ) others
FROM Client c
JOIN Users u USING (UserID) 
-- WHERE c.ClientID = 1
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1e89d0526c71951caeb93f213835bc65)